# Edit swagger definition for different routes in swashbuckle

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger

In our API we have two endpoints, one endpoint to create a resource and one endpoint to update a resource. We want to reuse the same model for both operations, but remove some of the properties in the swagger definition if the endpoint is a PUT-endpoint

Consider this model to create a user:

```
/// <summary>
/// Describes a User
/// </summary>
public class User 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Given name of the user
    /// </summary>
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Last name of the user
    /// </summary>
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Email address
    /// </summary>
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

The above code example is to create a `User` in our system. For our `PUT` endpoint, we want to expose functionality to update only the `FirstName` and `LastName`, not `EmailAddress` as this requires some integration with other systems. Our goal is to avoid having a separate model to update the user. We want to do something like this with our model:

```
/// <summary>
/// Describes a User
/// </summary>
public class User 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Given name of the user
    /// </summary>
    [Updatable]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Last name of the user
    /// </summary>
    [Updatable]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Email address
    /// </summary>
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

By adding an attribute to properties within our model, we want to create a filter in the SwaggerGeneration to remove all properties that's not marked with the `UpdatableAttribute`. I've looked at the `IParameterFilter`, `IOperationFilter` and `ISchemaFilter`, but none of them seems to fit our needs.

Is there something I've overlooked? Has anyone done this?